# incompatible types: AppBarMainBinding cannot be converted to View failure to complile

Tags: android, kotlin, data-binding

I have a nested included layouts in which i try to pass data binding.
the following code fails with the following error;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include
        layout="@layout/content_main"
        android:id="@+id/contentMain"/>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</layout>
```

> /.../ap_generated_sources/debug/out/com/example/.../databinding/ActivityMainBindingImpl.java:35: error: incompatible types: AppBarMainBinding cannot be converted to View
> , (com.example...databinding.AppBarMainBinding) bindings[1]
> ^

if I remove the layout, the code compiles but then app:params added to include wont work. What am I missing? how to fix? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, and it was resolved after deleting the build folder in app directory and it built again without any error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the "content_main" layout not include flag or any layout inside it. Add it and make rebuild you that will fix the issue.